# Connected components of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

Are the connected components of $\mathbb{Q}$ just the singleton elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. I think they are because a singleton is connected and the only connected sets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are singletons. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct assuming we take the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$. We can prove this statement as follows.

Let $q_1, q_2$ be arbitrary rational numbers. Pick an irrational number $i$ such that $q_1 < i < q_2$ (such a choice is possible because of density reasons). The sets $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x < i\}$ and $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x > i\}$ define a separation of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Perhaps under the assumption that we take the induced topology from $\mathbb R$...

Comment: Thanks. I added it to my post. @WhatsUp

Comment: @EkeshKumar So, here you showed that $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected. Now if I want to show that the only connected sets are the singletons, I would take a set that is not a singleton, call it $C$. There exist $x, y \in C$ such that $x \neq y$. Then take $(- \infty, i)$ and $(i, \infty)$ as a seperation for $C$ ($i$ being the irrational). Would that show that the only connected sets of $C$ are singletons?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @MikeLimber

Comment: @EkeshKumar Lastly, does this imply that connected components do not have to be open (because singletons are connected components here and they are not open in $\mathbb{Q}$)?

Comment: @MikeLimber connected components of $X$ are open iff $X$ is locally connected. And $\Bbb Q$ is not locally connected. They *are* always closed, though.

Comment: Is Q a discrete space,since connected sets are singletons?