# Find specific bijection to make Homeomorphism fit for theorem

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Source: *Conover,Robert:* A First Course In Topology

**Problem statement**

Recall the 1-1 correspondence between rationals and positive integers. Give both
the relative topology from the usual topology on R . Show that there is a
bijection between X and Y components of
the spaces with corresponding Homeomorphism but spaces themselves are Homeomorphism

The second part of this theorem I proved
already .

**Attempted proof** (rewrite)

(n-1,n+1)$\cap$ $Z^{+}$={n}

Let a,b are arbitrary rational numbers .Pick an irrational number i such that a<i<b then

U={x$\in $ Q:x<i}, V= {x$\in $ Q:x>i}

So U $\cap V=\emptyset$ and U $\cup V=Q$

The X connected component,{n}.

Y connected component is {x}

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3453932/960654

Since both sets are singletons,both should have a bijection

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ cannot be homeomorphic, since the first is discrete (every set is open), while the second is not. Also, I'm having difficulties understanding what the problem requires. What are an X component and a Y component? You mean connected components?

Comment: In both spaces $\Bbb Z^+$ and $\Bbb Q$ the connected components are the singletons. So any bijection is one also between components. But $\Bbb Q$ is crowded and $\Bbb Z^+$ is discrete (as you showed) so they're not homeomorphic.

Comment: The problem requires to show the X connected component and Y connected component are bijective with a corresponding homeomorphism @Alessandro

Comment: Ok. I corrected Q